# Increment counter or query relations?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, relational-database, scalability

Let's say I have a User model and a Favorite model. I want to know how many favorites a user has.

I see that you can accomplish this in two ways.

1. Atomically increment a counter attribute on the user model when a favorite is created. Access using `user_instance.favorite_count`
2. Query the favorite count for the user: `user_instance.favorite_set.count()`

I would imagine that as the DB grows, counting becomes more expensive.

Which implementation is more scalable?

Comment: 3. Add a `favorite_count` instance method that just calls `favorite_set.count()` and replace it with a counter if and when it seems to be a problem. Models are allowed to have methods right? They don't have to be simple bags of columns.

Comment: @muistooshort what's the difference between doing that and calling `user_instance.favorite_set.count()`? They're calling the same thing, so that seems redundant.

Comment: The difference is that you're hiding your choice of implementations behind a method. You can change your mind about your implementation (cached counter versus a database query) and nothing that uses your model will care.

Comment: @muistooshort I see now - thats a great idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I smell some premature optimization here. Databases are extremely good at counting things. Unless you have measured and are seeing some identifiable slowness, you should not attempt to denormalize: it is difficult to get right and always at risk of getting out of sync. Go with the query; and don't forget you can use aggregation to query the counts for a queryset of users at one time.

Comment: Sounds good - thanks!!